# How to map a vector to a different range in R?

Tags: r

I have a vector in the range `[1,10]`

```
c(1,2,9,10)
```

and I want to map it to a different range, for example `[12,102]`

```
c(12,22,92,102)
```

Is there a function that already does this in R?

Comment: Can you explain your mapping? I don't understand why 2 is mapped to 62 or why 270 is in there at all since it falls outside of your range.

Comment: Sorry @David, I mixed up two examples I was using to understand the problem. It's basically a linear mapping.

Comment: This should be obvious, but this is not an `R` question.  It's a question concerning basic linear algebra.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
linMap <- function(x, from, to)
  (x - min(x)) / max(x - min(x)) * (to - from) + from

linMap(vec, 12, 102)
# [1]  12  22  92 102
```

Or more explicitly:

```
linMap <- function(x, from, to) {
  # Shifting the vector so that min(x) == 0
  x <- x - min(x)
  # Scaling to the range of [0, 1]
  x <- x / max(x)
  # Scaling to the needed amplitude
  x <- x * (to - from)
  # Shifting to the needed level
  x + from
}
```

`rescale(vec, c(12, 102))` works using the package `scales`. Also one could exploit `approxfun` in a clever way as suggested by @flodel:

```
linMap <- function(x, a, b) approxfun(range(x), c(a, b))(x)
```

Comment: I have a temporal behaviour in your `linMap` and `rescale` where the some columns go to zero in R 3.3.2. Example values `all.dat <- c(2274959, 1531001)`. Do you know why?

Comment: @Masi, what do you mean by temporal behaviour? I suppose `all.dat` is `x` in my answer's notation. Then what is `from`, `to`, your expected output and what you are getting instead?

Comment: I get zero column instead.